# How to go back to MIUI from Cyanogen mod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, custom-roms, xiaomi, miui

I recently installed **Cyanogen mod 14.1(7.1.1)** on **Mi5(gemini)** and now I want to go back to MIUI (preferably **MIUI global developer rom**) and lock the bootloader. I have to tried to flash using the existing **TWRP** and also using the inbuilt **fastboot** mode, but was not successful. I can neither find a proper flashing guide nor the proper files required to flash. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Did you _not_ follow [this](http://en.miui.com/a-234.html)? Aside from using 9008 mode (not recommended), this is the most surefire way to do it. If you can't, get your drivers right.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't saved a backup with TWRP you have to reinstall the MIUI.

First of all download the ROM [here](http://en.miui.com/download-299.html).

Then put the ROM in a USB drive or SD card (it has to be read from the smartphone outside its own disk).

Then, install the ROM.

You can follow these steps from [How to Flash a New ROM to Your Android Phone](https://www.howtogeek.com/162516/how-to-flash-your-nexus-s-or-any-other-android-device-with-a-new-rom/)

But if you have a saved backup with TWRP, go to restore and select your backup.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

If you have backed up previous MIUI ROM(nandroid) using TWRP, you can restore MIUI by locating the backup file. Also, you can restore user apps from nandroid backup using Titanium backup.(Titanium backup pro have option to restore apps from nandroid backup).

Method 2:

If you don't have nandroid backup, then you need to reinstall MIUI. Download MIUI ROM from http://en.miui.com/download.html. And have a factory reset, to lock bootloader and remove root and replace stock recovery.

Comment: How do I lock the bootloader to unvoid warranty?

Comment: After installing MIUI, do a factory reset. It will lock bootloader. (Backup current, before any actions)

Comment: @RahulGopi How will a factory reset (essentially a data wipe) lock bootloader? It will not. Do it manually.

Comment: How do you do it manually?

Comment: @RahulGopi have you tried it? Does it work?

Comment: I have tried to unlock bootloader of my redmi 3s(MIUI). After that, I haven't get any updates, so I decide to lock bootloader. As, I am in MIUI, I have unchecked OEM unlocking in Developer options and do a fresh install of MIUI ROM and after that had a factory reset.

Comment: http://en.miui.com/thread-253680-1-1.html

Comment: @AndyYan how do I it manually

Comment: @Dhruva Have you looked at the guide? Or have you "@"'d the wrong person?

Comment: There is no guide! That's the reason I posted a question and I didn't '@' the wrong person @AndyYan

Comment: @Dhruva Huh? The link I left *is* a guide. Download appropriate file, enter fastboot, plug in, start flashing. What else do you need?